# Haskell error handling, log invalid file path to console

Tags: haskell, error-handling, console

As part of [this project](https://github.com/s-matthew-english/quorum), I'd like to validate the path of the file that's provided with passwords, i.e. `pwds <- case cfgPasswords of Just passPath -> (map (Just . T.unpack) . lines) <$> readFileUtf8 passPath`, in the case that the path for the file is not valid I'd like to log a message to that effect to the console.

How to accomplish this in Haskell?

```
logf' "Log level is {}" [show logLevel]
setLogLevel logLevel
debugf' "Configuration: {}" [show cfg]
ncpus <- getNumProcessors
logf' "Utilizing {} core(s)" [ncpus]
setNumCapabilities ncpus
pwds <- case cfgPasswords of
    Just passPath -> (map (Just . T.unpack) . lines) <$>
        readFileUtf8 passPath
    Nothing       -> return $ replicate (length cfgPublicKeys) Nothing
when (length cfgPublicKeys /= length cfgPrivateKeys) $
    errorL' "The same amount of public keys and private keys must be specified"
when (length cfgPublicKeys /= length pwds) $
    errorL' "The same amount of passwords must be included in the passwords file as the number of private keys. (If a private key has no password, include a blank line.)"
when (cfgPort == 0) $
    errorL' "A listening port must be specified with 'port' in the configuration file or --port at runtime"
```

The idea is that it would go right above the line `when (length cfgPublicKeys /= length cfgPrivateKeys) $`.

Comment: And what's the problem?

Comment: the problem is I don't know haskell really at all- how would I log such an error message to the console?

Comment: I can't find the haskell code in the project you linked could you show where it is more precisely?

Comment: This question has a lot of unnecessary information (like most of the code, which isn't even complete) and lacks a lot of necessary information (like what you've tried to do to accomplish the stated behaviour). Logging a message is easy (it's just `putStrLn`, or you seem to be using some other function `logf'`) - how do you want your program to proceed if the filepath given isn't valid? I see this as a much bigger issue, as I don't see a sensible way to do so; and a complete answer would likely required this information.

Comment: Here's a link to a [gist file with the context of the function I'm trying to implement](https://gist.github.com/s-matthew-english/41e18c23d34009bd7b69ed925b4ed2d8), as well as the attempt to modify the code as recommended in the answer below, the original file is [here](https://github.com/s-matthew-english/constellation/blob/master/Constellation/Node/Main.hs)

Comment: Hi Matthew. I notice that a large number of your titles are written in lower-case stylistically, and they are slowly being repaired by volunteer editors as they are noticed. Might I ask you to observe the standard case rules here (initial upper case, upper case for proper nouns)? It would save us a great deal of work. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure you have enough information in this code snippet for someone to deduce precisely what's going on here with you type signatures.

The project you've linked seems like it's written in go?

There appear to be a number of project specific functions that you're calling in your code example.

For the case of 'does this file path point to a file,' you'd do something like:

```
checkForAFile :: FilePath -> IO ()
checkForAFile path = do
    validFile <- doesFileExist path
    if validFile
       then putStrLn $ path ++ " is a file that exists"
       else putStrLn $ path ++ " is not a file that exists"
```

`doesFileExist` is a function available in the `System.Directory` library, and is the canonical way to answer your question of whether or not the filepath points to a file.

Not knowing what this code is doing, I can't suggest a proper place to toss in that check, but hopefully that's enough for you to go on.

If it isn't, I may suggest trying to whet your teeth on some Haskell code that has a little less going on.

Comment: So, I tried to implement this function, but- I'm very new to haskell- haven't been able to get it to click, [here's a link to a gist](https://gist.github.com/s-matthew-english/41e18c23d34009bd7b69ed925b4ed2d8) with the full file including these modifications, as well as the error message I got in my console.

Comment: My apologies. I updated the example function so that it actually compiles, and threw a comment up on your gist trying to explain a bit about what's going on there.

Comment: Thank you so much for this wonderful explanation :) I'm still new to Haskell and so this information is all fresh + extremely valuable for me. I've tried both invocations you suggested, but I ran into errors in each time, [here](https://gist.github.com/s-matthew-english/22dcc13e5d9c05069ea251cb43618636) is the first way you described- by the replicated pattern, and [this is in the piggy-back style](https://gist.github.com/s-matthew-english/d8c4e354d3df2f9efc7547c3ed0bbf38), I put the console output I ended up with as a comment at the end of both files

Answer (score 1):

In your linked [gist](https://gist.github.com/s-matthew-english/41e18c23d34009bd7b69ed925b4ed2d8#file-main-hs-L142) you have the following function causing a syntax error:

```
checkForAFile :: FilePath -> IO ()
checkForAFile path
    validFile <- doesFileExist filePath
    if validFile
       then putStrLn $ filePath ++ " is a file that exists"
       else putStrLn $ filePath ++ " is not a file that exists"
```

That's because you forgot the `=` sign. Use this instead:

```
checkForAFile :: FilePath -> IO ()
checkForAFile path = do
    validFile <- doesFileExist filePath
    if validFile
       then putStrLn $ filePath ++ " is a file that exists"
       else putStrLn $ filePath ++ " is not a file that exists"
```

Comment: cool, thank you for that insight- just tried re-running the code with this modification tho- and it wouldn't build- something about `Variable not in scope`, I put the full console output [here on this gist](https://gist.github.com/s-matthew-english/46de53159c61c097a440ce44875cf04c)